# VS Code jsconfig auto point to index.js

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I want to use absolute path in React Native using Visual Studio code. Follow this tutorial: [tuturial](https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1), I can make it work.

Example, in my SRC folder, I created `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@src"
}
```

But the intellisense doesn't work when I try to `import A from '@src/...'`, fix it by created `jsconfig.json` in the root:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@locale/*": ["locale/*"]
    },
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

And it works for the `from` part, but not `import` part, I've to put `/index` in order to make VS show hint, if the `/index` not there, the hint is not showing. Is there any way to make it work without putting `/index` in every import?

```
import { notShowHintHere } A from '@src/componentA'

import { showHintHere } A from '@src/componentA/index'
```

Comment: Can you share your folder structure and how are you exporting files?

Comment: in root folder, just created src/componentA folder, in componentA, there are 2 files, ComponentA.js and index.js (which only import and export ComponentA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24715, update the `compilerOptions.module` works

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
```

Comment: this didn't help, I am having the same issue

Comment: @MahdiPedram It didn't take effect until I've restarted my VSCode. (Just restarting TS server might work too.)